# What does connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js do

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm wondering, what features do the all.js from facebook add to the like button? - I'm trying to implement it, and found a really nice way, even without loading the all.js file, the like works just fine, it will get registered and anything..

But is there something that I will miss? If I just have a simple like button on my page?

Comment: That's the Facebook JavaScript SDK.

Comment: *all.js* contains the [Facebook JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/). You should only need to include it if you need any of the features provided by the SDK. The Like button widget code that Facebook generates for you will dynamically include it.

Comment: Generate free shadow profiles for Facebook among other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need all.js if you only want to use the like function.

The like function is so popular that there are standalone plugins, as you are using.

With all.js, you can do a lot more. For example posting stories on other peoples wall or accessing peoples personal data if they agree.

Answer (score -2):

At the moment, nothing at all. The site is down or that script may have been moved.